# Why the time is never printing correctly?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Why its printing always invalid time? `PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2016 21:48:49)`

Output:  05:11:00
Expected output: 05:00:00

CODE:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Luxembourg');
$hour = '05';
$minute = '00';
$time = date('H:m:i', strtotime($hour . ':' . $minute . ':00'));
echo $time;
exit;
```

Comment: use 

date("H:i");

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Aside from using the wrong predefined date constant (`m`) why go through the manipulation when you could just `$time = $hour . ':' . $minute . ':00';`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`m` means "month". It is November, hence 11.

Did you mean `date('H:i:s')`?

Answer (score 1):

In your date() call, you're specifying:
H - 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros. 
m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros. 
i - Minutes with leading zeros.

And this is indeed November, the 11th month.

Answer (score 0):

You used m in date, thats why. You should use i instead of m:

> m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros - 01 through 12
>
> i - Minutes with leading zeros - 00 to 59

You can check how to format here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever print time then date format like (H:i:s)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Luxembourg');
$hour = '05';
$minute = '15';
$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($hour . ':' . $minute . ':00'));

echo $time;
exit;
```

Make sure this is a helpful to you